# AdMob AdView SDK 6.0.1 memory usage

Tags: memory, admob, allocation, adview

I try to include an AdMob banner in my Android App using the AdMobsAdsSdk6.0.1.
The banner shows up correctly but increases the displayed memory-usage in the phones task manager from 2 MB to 10 MB. DDMS shows approx. 5MB. I have read some articles about possible memory leaks in older versions, but could not find anything solving my problem. I reproduced the behavior with a simple test app.

The Activity only holds the AdView

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private AdView adView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "adunitid");
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_Layout);
        layout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
                adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

The Manifest is also only a copy from the tutorial

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="admobtest.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I also tried to include the banner via xml but i finally get the same results. Switching to landscape and back raises the memory further and further. Am i missing something or can somebody give me some hint how to solve this? I thought adView.destroy solved the memory leak.